# How structs are extended just importing packages in D?

Tags: import, d

I have this fibonacci number generator.

```
struct FibonacciSeries
{
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;

    enum empty = false;

    @property int front() const
    {
        return first;
    }

    void popFront()
    {
        int third = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = third;
    }

    @property FibonacciSeries save() const
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This struct does not have the `take` method, so I have this error when executing this command (`writeln(FibonacciSeries().take(5))`).

```
a.d(66): Error: no property 'take' for type 'FibonacciSeries'
```

However, by importing `range` package, it has the `take` method. What's the mechanism behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mechanism is Uniform Function Call Syntax:

http://dlang.org/function.html#pseudo-member

To put it simply, if `a.foo(b...)` is not valid, the compiler tries rewriting it to `foo(a, b...)`.